# RegularExpressionValidator breaks javascript ui datepiker

Tags: javascript, java, c#, asp.net, datepicker

So i am working on a asp.net web page.  I am using asp:textboxes with a javascript datepicker but i am running into a problem when i put a Regular Expression Validator on another textbox that doesn't have a javascrips datepicker on it.  The datepickers will not show up.  But once i remove the validator it works.  Below is the code from my aspx page. Let me know what i can do to get this to work.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h1>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPageHeaderTitle" runat="server" Text="Accident Report Form"></asp:Label>
</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtDateOfInjury.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtFirstDataAway.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtLastDateLost.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtReturnToWorkDate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtRestrictionStartDate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtRestrictionEndDate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtDateReturnJOI.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=txtDateOfDeath.ClientID%>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeInfo" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">Employee Information</asp:Label>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEmployeeInfo" runat="server" Width="98%" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">

    <table cellpadding="3" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; ">
                <strong><span style="color: #ff0000">&nbsp;&nbsp; * = Required</span></strong>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: Right; color: black;">Accident #:
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAccidentReportNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

<tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black; ">Date of Birth:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left; ">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfBirth" runat="server" ToolTip="mm/dd/yyyy" TabIndex="1" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valDateOfBirth" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateOfBirth" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a valid date(mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black; ">Data of Hire:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left; ">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfHire" runat="server" ToolTip="mm/dd/yyyy" TabIndex="1" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Label ID="lblAccidentInformation" runat="server" Font-Bold="True">Accident Information</asp:Label>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAccidentInformation" runat="server" Width="98%" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <br />
    <table cellpadding="3" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black;">Location of Accident:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccidentLocation" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black; ">Accident Type:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccidentType" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black; ">Incident Time:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIncidentTimeHour" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> &nbsp : &nbsp
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIncidentTimeMinuet" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="btnIncidentTimeAM" runat="server"  Text="AM"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="btnIncidentTimePM" runat="server"  Text="PM"></asp:RadioButton>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black;">Doing Before Incident:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoingBeforeIncident" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; color: black; ">Date of Injury:</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfInjury" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
```

Comment: Did you try putting the `script` block at the end of the markup?

Comment: I tried putting it at the end but it is still a no go.  Thanks